# how to get all value from broadcast intent one by one?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

i am working on app in which i have to send multiple contact at a time

here is a sms code where i am sending different indices at time but at broadcast i am just getting update one for example  , sending 0 1 2 but getting only 2 as USER_ID key

```
override fun sendSms(sms: Sms) {
    sms.userList.forEachIndexed { index, contact ->

        val sentIntent = Intent(SmsService.SENT)

        sentIntent.putExtra(SmsService.MESSAGE_ID ,sms.messages.messageId)
        sentIntent.putExtra(SmsService.USER_ID , index) // here i am send different index 

        val sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(smsService.applicationContext, 0, sentIntent,  PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or   PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
       
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(
                contact.phone,
                null,
                sms.messages.message,
                sentPI,
                deliveryPI)
                   }   }



 // here is the send boadcast code i want to get all index value but i am just getting updated one for example i am sending index 0 1 2 but not getting index 2 so want to retrieve all the value one by one 




           /************* Sent BroaddCast **************/
private val sentBroadcast =object : BroadcastReceiver(){
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {

        println("Send Broadcast")




                when(resultCode){
                    Activity.RESULT_OK ->{
                        if(intent!=null ) {
                            val messageId = intent.getLongExtra(MESSAGE_ID, 0)
                            val userId = intent.getIntExtra(USER_ID, 0)

                            val scheduleMessage = smsScheduler.getSentMessages()
                            println("Sucessfull message "  + messageId +"userId"+userId)

                        }
                    }

                   

                }
```

} }

Comment: Change the `0` in the `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` call to `index`.

Comment: @MikeM. thanks it is working now

Comment: You should add an answer and accept that answer, or delete the question. Otherwise this question stays on the list of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `0` in the

```
val sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(smsService.applicationContext, 0, sentIntent,  PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or   PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
```

to `index`, like this

```
`val sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(smsService.applicationContext, index, sentIntent,  PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or   PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)`
```